# Generating links for attribution with Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-dynamic-links

It may be that I just don't understand what Firebase is doing with attribution, but I'd like to be able to create links that I can use in certain marketing spots that are not through one of the Firebase-selectable networks, but that will still allow me to collect attribution data for the use of those links. It seems at first that using Dynamic Links could work, but I'm not seeing the campaigns showing up in the Attribution tab in the console.

What's the best way to generate links I can use to be able to attribute conversions from non-ad networks, marketing emails, etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your Dynamic Links or URL/Universal Links that open the apps should have some "utm_" params like "utm_source" or "utm_campaign". For example, assume that your app can be opened with a universal link 
"https://testapp.xyz?utm_campaign=test_campaign&utm_source=test_source"
Then when the app is opened with that link, it will log a campaign event automatically.

Make sure that you don't disable the App Delegate Proxy (FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled should not be NO). If you did set it to NO, make sure that you call the handlers as instructed in **FIRAnalytics (AppDelegate)**.

One way to test it is turning on debug mode (you can view real-time traffic under [DebugView](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview) tab), and opening your app with the link. Make sure that a campaign event is logged and sent to [DebugView](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7201382?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489).

The attribution will happen if there is some conversion event happen after the campaign event is logged. For example, a user can make an in-app-purchase/e-commerce event and it will be attributed to the campaign event.

Besides automatic campaign events, you can log [campaign_details](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event.html#CAMPAIGN_DETAILS) event yourself in your URL handler.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Going to attempt to implement this now.